# UTF-16 Encoding in Java versus C#

Tags: c#, java, encoding, md5, utf-16

I am trying to read a String in UTF-16 encoding scheme and perform MD5 hashing on it. But strangely, Java and C# are returning different results when I try to do it.

The following is the piece of code in **Java**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "preparar mantecado con coca cola";
    try {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(str.getBytes("UTF-16"));
        byte[] hash = digest.digest();
        String output = "";
        for(byte b: hash){
            output += Integer.toString( ( b & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring( 1 );
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

The output for this is: **249ece65145dca34ed310445758e5504**

The following is the piece of code in **C#**:

```
   public static string GetMD5Hash()
        {
            string input = "preparar mantecado con coca cola";
            System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider x = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input);
            bs = x.ComputeHash(bs);
            System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte b in bs)
            {
                s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
            }
            string output= s.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
```

The output for this is: **c04d0f518ba2555977fa1ed7f93ae2b3**

I am not sure, why the outputs are not the same. How do we change the above piece of code, so that both of them return the same output?

Comment: Compare your byte arrays first. If they mismatch in even a single bit, the hashes are completely different. There may a BOM or whatever in the UTF-16 encoding. It may be little or big endian, or whatever.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

UTF-16 != UTF-16.

In Java, `getBytes("UTF-16")` returns an a big-endian representation with optional byte-ordering mark. C#'s `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` returns a little-endian representation. I can't check your code from here, but I think you'll need to specify the conversion precisely.

Try `getBytes("UTF-16LE")` in the Java version.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you look at the output in eclipse, it still doesn't match what Visual Studio shows you. But strangely it does work...

Comment: 2015, Java 8.0 * .NET 4.0.x tests based on Polish language, seems be OK like Yoy write. Bytes in both languages are identical, and have *not*  BOM prefix. Next important field for tests: Java arithmetic accept overflow silently (good for hash), C# by default not

Answer (score 5):

The first thing I can find, and this might not be the only problem, is that  C#'s Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes() is littleendian, while Java's natural byte order is bigendian.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `System.Text.Enconding.Unicode.GetString(byte[])` to convert back from byte to string. In this way you're sure that all happens in Unicode encoding.